Issue with Invalid Sync Tokens Response in Apple MDM Declarative Management
Create JSON Request:
I created a JSON request that includes a TokensResponse as follows:
{
  "TokensResponse": {
    "SyncTokens": {
      "DeclarationsToken": "125412312312312",
      "Timestamp": "2024-05-27T12:00:00Z"
    }
  }
}

Convert JSON to Base64:
I used Java to convert the JSON to Base64:
import java.util.Base64;

public class JsonToBase64 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"TokensResponse\": {\n" +
                "    \"SyncTokens\": {\n" +
                "      \"DeclarationsToken\": \"125412312312312\",\n" +
                "      \"Timestamp\": \"2024-05-27T12:00:00Z\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jsonString.getBytes());
        System.out.println(base64Encoded);
    }
}


The generated Base64 encoded string is:
ewogICJUb2tlbnNSZXNwb25zZSI6IHsKICAgICJTeW5jVG9rZW5zIjogewogICAgICAiRGVjbGFyYXRpb25zVG9rZW4iOiAiMTI1NDEyMzEyMzEyMzEyIiwKICAgICAgIlRpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIyMDI0LTA1LTI3VDEyOjAwOjAwWiIKICAgIH0KICB9Cn0K

Create Command.plist File:
I inserted the generated Base64 encoded string into the Data field of the Command.plist file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>DeclarativeManagement</string>
        <key>Data</key>
        <string>ewogICJUb2tlbnNSZXNwb25zZSI6IHsKICAgICJTeW5jVG9rZW5zIjogewogICAgICAiRGVjbGFyYXRpb25zVG9rZW4iOiAiMTI1NDEyMzEyMzEyMzEyIiwKICAgICAgIlRpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIyMDI0LTA1LTI3VDEyOjAwOjAwWiIKICAgIH0KICB9Cn0K</string>
        <key>RequestRequiresNetworkTether</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>32db01a085c04acbba04daec5f5926c7</string>
</dict>
</plist>


Send Command:
I sent the command to the device through the MDM server.
Error Encountered
The device returned the following error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>32db01a085c04acbba04daec5f5926c7</string>
    <key>ErrorChain</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ErrorCode</key>
            <integer>1100</integer>
            <key>ErrorDomain</key>
            <string>RMErrorDomain</string>
            <key>LocalizedDescription</key>
            <string>MDM request failed: Cannot refresh management channel because the sync tokens response is invalid.</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Status</key>
    <string>Error</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>00008020-000A59891A81002E</string>
</dict>
</plist>


Does anyone know if there's a link problem? Thanks in advance
